# Ground Planes, 0v or GND?

Tags: pcb-design, ground, isolation, pcb-layers, ground-plane

I have a board that has a dual voltage isolated DC-DC converter on it.

The converter takes 0 an 5v in and gives -5,0,5 v out.

The 0v of the input is actual ground.

Most of the PCB uses the isolated voltages.

Should I use ground and 5V (input) as my planes?

Or should I use 0v (isolated) for the underside plane, and some other value for the top side plane?

Comment: Show a schematic please

Comment: The power plane potentials should be those that the components right above are actually using, otherwise the loop area is not minimized defeating the purpose of a plane.

Comment: @VoltageSpike It's essentially an audio opamp circuilt with the opamp being powered from both positive and negative outputs of a DC-DC converter.
So I could use the 0v as one plane, but what to use at the other plane?